# Ionic v1 - SQLite database getting deleted when storage is full on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

Our team is using SQLite for storage on an Ionic v1 app. It appears that whenever the storage fills up on iOS, the operating system is deleting the database. Ideally, we'd like this data to be persistent.

Initially, our code to create the DB looked like this:

```
self.db = window.openDatabase('example', '1.0', 'ExampleDb', 3*1024*1024);
```

After doing some research, I decided to try this plugin: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

The code now looks like this:

```
self.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDatabase({name: 'example', location: 'default'});
```

I have tried using all of the provided locations: `default`, `Library`, and `Documents` but the database is still being removed by the OS. Is there anything I'm missing about persistent storage?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!